# QT Widget Disappears when there are No Children

Tags: qt, layout

Using Qt5, I am trying to develop an app having widgets arranged in columns. The widgets are created by the following code:

```
QWidget *area = new QWidget(centralWidget);
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(area);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  columns.push_back(new QWidget(area));
  layout->addWidget(columns[i]);
  layouts2.push_back(QVBoxLayout());
  labels.push_back(new QVector<QLabel *>);
  for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
    labels[i].push_back(new QLabel(columns[i]));
    layouts2[i]->addWidget(labels[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Later, labels can be added or deleted from columns.  The code to delete a label is:

```
QLabel *label = labels[i][j];
layouts2[i]->removeWidget(label);
delete label;
labels[i].pop_back();
```

Eventually, a column has all of its labels deleted.  I had hoped that the column widget, even with no children, would serve as a place-holder and leave the display as before, with a blank where the empty column should be.  Instead, the column is eliminated from the display and only the n-1 columns appear.  What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve but I suspect the problem lies with the default implementation of `QWidget::sizeHint`...

```
QSize QWidget::sizeHint() const
{
    Q_D(const QWidget);
    if (d->layout)
        return d->layout->totalSizeHint();
    return QSize(-1, -1);
}
```

If the widget has a layout then `sizeHint` returns the size required by the layout which, if the layout is empty, will probably be `QSize(0, 0)`.

If you want the widget in question to be visible in some way even after removing all items from its layout then try calling [`QWidget::setMinimumSize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMinimumSize-1) with a suitable value.

Comment: Thanks.  setMinimumSize() was what I needed.